# Dynamically add a column to datagrid or generate datagrid with specific columns from a list

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I've been struggling with `datagrid` `databinding` for days now..

I am trying to generate `datagrid` dynamically from a `list` of custom objects.
Because the number of list-object properties that I need to display might change, I don't know exact number of columns, nor their headers.

So I thought, I'd dynamically add only the columns I need and create bindings (to the specific object properties) for them. After that I would fill in the `datagrid` with data from a `list` based on the bindings.

For example:

I create an empty `datagrid`

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,31" Grid.RowSpan="2">
   </DataGrid>
```

I create my list, to store my data and the data object:

```
Public Class Res
    Public Shared TableData As New List(Of DataItem)
End Class

Public Class DataItem
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property MyProperty() As String
    Public Property Prop() As String
    Public Property Prop1() As String
End Class
```

Now, say I want to show only the `Name` column in my `datagrid`, so I add a column with specific binding (presumably this is where the problem lies, yet I can't figure it out):

```
    Dim col As New DataGridTextColumn
    Dim bb As New Binding

    bb.Path = New PropertyPath("Name")
    bb.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    bb.Source = Res.TableData

    col.Binding = bb
    col.Header = "Name"

    MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(col)
```

Then, I finally create and add some data to my list:

```
    Dim entry As New DataItem

    entry.Name = "Test Name"
    entry.MyProperty = "Test Property"
    entry.Prop = "one Entry"

    Res.TableData.Add(entry)

    Me.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = Res.TableData
```

Now the result is, that the entire column is filled with that same data. Where my intention was to fill only the row that corresponds to the exact `list` item. For example, if I later want to add another item to the `list` with a different "Name" it should be shown in the `datagrid` as another row with a different "Name" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to bind your grid to your List property, have AutoGenerateColumns = True and listen to AutoGeneratingColumn there you decide if you want to add that column to grid or not.

Comment: Ok, since I'm relatively new to WPF, I have no idea what are you suggesting. I guess I'll try to look into how to listen to AutoGeneratingColumn.

Comment: I guess you have a logic about what columns are to be added to your grid isn't ?

So, let grid autoGenerate and when it is generating check you logic there and decide whether to add or not..

let me know if you need clarification

Comment: Got it working. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) helped. Though this feels kinda strange, it works. Thanks for the idea!